# Dynamic parameter cannot be resolved in Gauge

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, bdd, getgauge

i try to use the `file` special parameter in a Gauge specification.

```
Export a customer
----------------------------------------
* Find customer "Hans"
* Export customer to <file:/customer.xml>
```

The java implementation for this looks like this

```
@Step("Export customer to <file>")
public void test(String file) {
   System.out.println("file " + file);
}
```

I assume the parameter typ is `String` (can it also be `File` ?)

But nevertheless, running this, returns

```
[ParseError] C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\qmsgauge\specs\tenantManagement.spec:40 
 Dynamic parameter <file:/customer.xml> could not be resolved => 'Export customer to <file:/customers.xml>'
Successfully generated html-report to => C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\qmsgauge\reports\html-report\index.html
```

How do I define the file parameter in the spec and how do need to write the java implementation for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Path starting with "/" assumes that it is the root. If a relative path is used do not start with "/"

so the parameter value can be - file:specs/example.spec

Comment: that was one of the problems - other was my assumption that the file does not need to exists... which it does